# How can I add a spring bean to a Spring Boot test class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an integration test which makes use of a test helper class. Currently I create this test helper class with the junit `BeforeEach` method:

```
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@SpringBootTest
public class EmployeeControllerIT {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    
    private TestHelper testHelper;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        this.testHelper = new TestHelper();
    }

    ...
}
```

However, given I am using Spring, I'd like to use dependency injection. How can I add `TestHelper` to the application context so I can autowire it as follows:

```
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@SpringBootTest
public class EmployeeControllerIT {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    
    @Autowired
    private TestHelper testHelper;

    ....
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of initializing the `TestHelper` in the `@BeforeEach` method, add a static inner class annotated with `@TestConfiguration` and declare the `TestHelper` as a bean:

```java
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@SpringBootTest
public class EmployeeControllerIT {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    
    @Autowired
    private TestHelper testHelper;

    @TestConfiguration
    public static class TestConfig {
        @Bean
        public TestHelper testHelper(SomeClass someClass) {
            return new TestHelper(someClass);
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: If ```TestHelper``` expects a dependency using constructor injection, how would I handle that with this solution? I can't specify it in the constructor - Spring should inject it. efire-net's solution handles this case, but I'd be interested in how that would work when explicitly defining the config as you are doing here.

Comment: You can pass the arguments like you would normally do in a `@Configuration` JavaConfig class. I have updated the example to demonstrate how a dependency of type`SomeClass` could be injected in the bean.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried annotating TestHelper with @Component?

Comment: Why is this downvoted? Since @SpringBootTest is used the whole applicationContext is being scanned and therefore if the application follows a correct folder structure annotating the class with Component would actually work.